# How to end process on localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I have a node app running on localhost:8080 in Chrome.  I need to end this process so I can run others on the same port.  But, even after a reboot, if I restart Chrome and access localhost:8080, the app is still there, and any other app that tries to access the port won't open.  Based on my research, using cmd to open the terminal, and typing "netstat -aon | findstr 8080" (or :8080) should show what process is listening there, but I get no response.  I downloaded TCPView - nothing is listed for port 8080.

How do I kill this app and make the port available?

Comment: Did you closed your node process from cmd?  Using `ctrl+c`

Comment: Run TCPView as Administrator.  There's probably a process you can't see with your normal user account.

Comment: The problem wasn't with the port.  It wasn't associated with any process, so I couldn't close it.  The problem was the service worker.  I was able to use Chrome dev tools to look at any running service workers, then unregister the one for the app.  That stopped it, and allowed the port to be available for other apps,